# Wrong ordering when insert DIV onto parent DIV

Tags: html

Parent DIV has

```
width: 100%;
padding: 5px;
display: grid;
grid-template-columns: 33% 33% 33%;
```

I have tried both ways to insert child DIV onto parent DIV

`document.getElementById("divParent").appendChild(document.createRange().createContextualFragment(l_strChild));`

or

`document.getElementById("divParent").innerHTML += l_strChild;`

l_strChild is just a DIV tag string.

I inserted in the right ordered list. But above produces order randomly. Anything I do wrong ?

Comment: When you inspect your div in browser, the order still is randomly?

Comment: I have ordered list, but after insert onto the parent, i inspected in Firefox order is wrong.

Comment: Please share your html full code so that I can be involved to research

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved. It is my mistake. I do insert child onto parent in image onload. As such, some image loaded fast, and some slow. This causes wrong order.